# Get data from server and use it in polymer element

Tags: ajax, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I would appreciate some help in something I'm trying to do with Polymer.
I have an element:

```
<dom-module id="internal-content">
  <template>
    <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment iron-positioning"></style>
    <style>
      internal-menu{
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      internal-associates, internal-networks, internal-letter, internal-help{
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="horizontal center layout">
      <internal-menu></internal-menu>

      <internal-associates id="internal-associates" data="{{userData.associates}}"></internal-associates>
      <internal-networks id="internal-networks" data="{{userData.socialNetworks}}" style="display: none"></internal-networks>
      <internal-letter id="internal-letter" data="{{userData.farewellLetter}}" style="display: none"></internal-letter>
      <internal-help id="internal-help" style="display: none"></internal-help>
    </div>

    <paper-toast-error id="errorInServer"
  text="Ha habido un problema en servidor al acceder a sus datos. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo. Si el error persiste póngase en contacto con nosotros
  a través del email v.punzano@gmail.com">
    </paper-toast-error>

  </template>
<script>
  (function() {
    'use strict';
    Polymer({
      is: 'internal-content',
      properties: {
        userData: {
          type: Object
        }
      },

      ready: function(){
       $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/getUserData",
         data: {firebaseID: document.querySelector('#firebaseLogin').user.uid},
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           document.querySelector('#errorInServer').openToast();
         },
         success: function(msg) {
           this.userData = msg;
           // return msg;
         }
       });
     }
   });
 })();
```

What I want to do is render the elements internal-associates, internal-networks and internal-letter with the data retrieved in the ajax call, in order to use the dom-repeat templates inside this elements to render the arrays within the data.

The problem with the code I attach here is that the elements have been registered in the DOM before the data is retrieved.

I can attached or provide more information if needed.

Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using [iron-ajax](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) for `ajax` call or if you are using `firebase` then [firebase-collection](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element).

Comment: Is your `include` in first `style` tag working?

Comment: Registering an element before providing data to it is never an issue with Polymer. Your actual issue seems to be with `this.userData`, here `this` does not seem to represent your element. You can check this by logging `this` inside your `success` function.

Comment: In general i'd recommend you to stick to vanilla js inside Polymer elements as other javascripts(like `jquery`) might not be aware of how to work with `shadow-dom`.

Comment: Thanks to you too @a1626.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Use iron-ajax instead of jquery: Whereas using external libraries is per se no issue, using iron-ajax can simplify your code a lot
2. As pointed out by @a1626 the `this` in your success handler is not the Polymer object you wish to use here
3. Your update code (`this.userData = msg;`) won't force Polymer to update the object. Use `this.set('userData', msg);` instead.
4. If you really have issues with your Subnodes hide them while you don't have any data. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if

Comment: It works! Using iron-ajax solved my problem. I have to recognize that I didn't realized that I were in another context inside the success event but, mainly, my problem was due to the lifecycle of Polymer beacause I tried other posibilities but all of them failed. 
Thank you very much @Kjell.